# Correct Format to Eval in an Apache 2.4 String in the Config File

Tags: configuration, apache-2.4

I've read the documentation on Apache 2.4 Expr, but can't get it to work in the config file. Can someone give me an example of how to format the expression inside a string? The docs say the following should work.

```
# Function example in string context
Header set foo-checksum "expr=%{md5:foo}"
```

But when I cut and paste that code into my config file, I get the following error:

```
Unrecognized header format %
```

I also tried these:

```
Header set exprResult "expr=tolower('MAKEMELOWERCASE')"
Header set exprResult "expr=%{tolower('MAKEMELOWERCASE')}"
Header set exprResult "(tolower('MAKEMELOWERCASE'))"
Header set exprResult "${tolower('MAKEMELOWERCASE')}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, once you've got a valid variable (Apache 2.4.7), this will work:

```
Header set myHeaderName "%{REQUEST_URI}e"
```

You just have to append an 'e' to the end of the string. Now setting your own variables (for output in a string) is buggy. Declare doesn't work. There's a workaround though. Use mod_rewrite to set the var. Here's an example.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=INFO_REQUEST_URI:%{REQUEST_URI}]
Header set X-Request-URI "%{INFO_REQUEST_URI}e"
```

Comment: What is that `e` supposed to do?  Is that documented somewhere??